# How to Interpolate One Segment of One Column in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a dataframe in python as below.

[image]

Say I change the value of second and forth rows as below.

[image]

Now I need to do interpolate from the second row to the forth row as below.

[image]

I'm new to this topic. Can anyone give me some ideas or the right function I can call for this problem. Thanks

Comment: Please don't use images of data. Provide a reproducible `Dataframe` constructor. Also explain how this would generalize, here the easiest would be to compute the value manually

Answer (score 1):

The exact expected logic is unclear, but you can mask the values and [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df.loc[2:2, 'value'] = np.nan

df['value'] = df['value'].interpolate()
```

Output:

```
       date  value
0  2023-1-1    1.0
1  2023-1-2    6.0
2  2023-1-3    6.5
3  2023-1-4    7.0
4  2023-1-5    5.0
```